# Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations even though all the required permission is in the manifest

Tags: parsing

Hello ive been getting this problem ive been deploying my app but i keep getting this error

11-23 11:25:23.381 18936-18987/nandos.android.appmy E/com.parse.PushService: Tried to use push, but this app is not configured for push due to: Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to support either GCM or PPNS for push (or both). To enable GCM support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root  element:

```
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
                                                                         <permission android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

                                                                         Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:

                                                                         <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
                                                                         <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                                                                           <intent-filter>
                                                                             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                                                                             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                                                                             <category android:name="nandos.android.appmy" />
                                                                           </intent-filter>
                                                                         </receiver>
                                                                         To enable PPNS support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:

                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
                                                                         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

                                                                         Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:

                                                                         <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
                                                                         <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
                                                                           <intent-filter>
                                                                             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                                                                             <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                                                                           </intent-filter>
                                                                         </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my manifest:

```
enter code here <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<!--Required permission for JPush-->
<permission
    android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.JPUSH_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.JPUSH_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_USER_PRESENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<!-- Optional. Required for location feature -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<!--Required permission for JPush-->


<uses-permission android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="nandos.android.appmy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="nandos.android.appmy.ui.activities.NandoApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Nandos_actionbar">
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />



    <!--Release Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBfGUWQYewQ2grdwckW0cyYUyGy7-qHugw" />
    <!--AIzaSyBfGUWQYewQ2grdwckW0cyYUyGy7-qHugw-->
    <!--AIzaSyBtOtmmPuaXb_B2PfBvvRUOapBTnO7w4k4   testing-->
    <activity
        android:name="nandos.android.lib.ui.activities.contact.ContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nandos.android.appmy.ui.activities.OverrideMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="myapp"
                android:scheme="nando"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.menu.OverrideMenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nandos.android.appmy.ui.activities.NewContactUsActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nandos.android.appmy.ui.activities.tabletalk.TableTalkerMainActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="nandos.android.appmy.ui.activities.OverrideRestaurantsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.LoyaltyActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.socialhub.SocialHubActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.socialhub.SocialHubDetails_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--JPush Requirements-->
    <activity
        android:name="cn.jpush.android.ui.PopWinActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyDialogStyle"
        android:exported="false">
    </activity>
    <!-- Required SDK Core functions-->
    <activity
        android:name="cn.jpush.android.ui.PushActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.ui.PushActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="nandos.android.appmy" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Required  SDK Core functions-->
    <service
        android:name="cn.jpush.android.service.DownloadService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>


    <!-- Required SDK Core functions-->
    <!-- Configurable android:process Parameter PushService In other processes -->
    <service
        android:name="cn.jpush.android.service.PushService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.REGISTER" />
            <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.REPORT" />
            <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.PushService" />
            <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.PUSH_TIME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- since 1.8.0 option Optional. For the same equipment in different applications JPush Services to each other pull function. -->
    <!-- If this feature is enabled to remove the component will not pull up other applications other applications can not be pulled -->
    <service
        android:name="cn.jpush.android.service.DaemonService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.DaemonService" />
            <category android:name="nandos.android.appmy" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <!-- Required SDK Core functions-->
    <receiver
        android:name="cn.jpush.android.service.PushReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="cn.jpush.android.intent.NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED_PROXY" />   <!--Required  显示通知栏 -->
            <category android:name="nandos.android.appmy" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Optional -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
    <!-- Required SDK Core functions-->
    <receiver android:name="cn.jpush.android.service.AlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        />
    <!--JPush Requirements-->

    <receiver
        android:name="nandos.android.appmy.ui.activities.pushNotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="nandos.android.appmy" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="nandos.android.appmy.ui.activities.pushNotification.GCMNotificationIntentService" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="nandos.android.appmy" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
        android:value="2c2ff6e3c30f2c8d1dc8d90718b5ce4c2d4c96f5" />

    <!--Call the JPush channel and App Key-->
    <meta-data android:name="JPUSH_CHANNEL" android:value="developer-default"/>
    <meta-data android:name="JPUSH_APPKEY" android:value="08e8c5fb8b4c587351bce7f0"/>

</application>
```

`enter code here`